# Firestore array-not-contains alternative solution

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

### TL-DR

I have created a Flutter Firestore posts application. I want to present the user only new posts, **which they didn't read yet**.

**How do I achieve that using Firestore query?**

### The problem

Each time a user sees a post, their id is added to the post `views` field.

Next time the user opens the app, I want to present only posts they didn't read yet.

The problem is that query `array-not-contains` is not supported. How do I achive that functionality?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're going to have a real hard time with this because Firestore can only give you documents where you know something about the contents of that document.  That's how indexes work - by recording data present in the document.  Indexes don't track data *not* present in a document because that's basically an infinite amount of data.

If you are trying to track documents seen by the user, you would think to mark the document as "seen" using a boolean per user, or tracking the document ID somewhere.  But as you can see, you can only query for documents that the user has seen, because that's the data present in the system.

What you can do is query for *all* documents, then query for all the documents the user has seen, then subtract the seen documents from all documents in order to get the unseen documents.  But this probably doesn't scale in a way you'd like.  (It's essentially the same problem with Firestore indexes not being able to surface documents without some known data present.  Firestore won't do the equivalent of a SQL table scan, since that would be a lot of reads you'd have to pay for.)

You can kind of fake it by making sure there is a creation timestamp in each document, and record for each user the timestamp of the most recent seen document.  If you require that the user must view the documents in chronological order, then you can simply query for documents with a creation timestamp greater than the timestamp of the latest document seen by the user.  This is really as good as it's going to get with Firestore, since you can't query for the absence of data.